# $http Service fails with status -1

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

### Can't use AngularJS properly with jQuery and Adobe panel creation

I needed to update versions for AngularJS and jQuery for project. The old versions was jquery-1.11.0.min.js and angularJS 1.2.10. And now I would like to use newest available versions that are angularJS 1.7.8 and jQuery 3.4.1. Generally I am using everything like it has been used here but without any framework - https://medium.com/adobetech/how-to-create-your-first-adobe-panel-in-6-easy-steps-f8bd4ed5778

But when I'm using new versions I have very often many errors that are so inexplicably. Main thing what I am thinking is that it jQuery is somehow conflicting with angularJS. Here is my code -

```
<script src="lib/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/CSInterface.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="StartCtrl">
<div>
    <form name="modifyApp" class="form-signin" ng-submit="testMethod(vars)">
        <input type="text" placeholder="" class="" autocapitalize="off" id="token" ng-model="vars.token">
        <button class="button-text background login-button">Validate token</button>
    </form>
    <button type="submit" ng-href='#here' ng-click="doSomething()" class="inline button button-text background">Do something</button>
</div>
```

Then there is imported controllers.js file where is the `StartCtrl`. I also needed to put services in the same file where controllers because I can't reach services.js file from controllers.js I don't know why.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])

app.controller('StartCtrl',['$scope', '$http', 'Test', function($scope, $http, Test) {

    $scope.vars = {
        token: 'vgs7mJR7icPgMO2aOQAjzl71e8k5mwGx1OQncsefMl7OyPj8tgKfkvrSNpOi',
        search: ''
    };

    $scope.axleSpeechMinutesLeft = function(vars) {
    var inputToken = $scope.vars.token;
        Test.getSomething(inputToken).then(function (response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    }
}]);

app.service('Test', function ($rootScope, $http) {
    this.getSomething = function(token) {
        $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'https://testurl2019.com',
          headers: {"Authorization" : "Bearer " + token},
        }).then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
          }, function (response) {
            return response;
        });
    };
})
```

From here I am able to get to the $http request that responds me this rather strange error. BTW the old versions for project I used worked on mac perfectly but not on windows(with the same code, I saw handlebars in the panel and a lot errors), so I took newest jquery and angularJS versions and now trying to run this on windows by rewriting old version code. Here are the error pic from $http.
[image]

I will highly appreciate your help!

Comment: Image is at the very button giving me no proper info. Though I used the same $http code for the old versions for project and it was working. And I also saw it in different tutorials used like this.

Comment: https://ibb.co/bJR5NBm 
This is all I have in dev console.
[undefined] is from

        `Test.getSomething(inputToken).then(function (response){
            console.log(response);
        }`

Comment: This looks like a "Russian Doll" problem. Fix the problem with status `-1`, lift the Russian Doll to find another, `Test.getSomething(inputToken)` returns `undefined`.

Comment: Sorry I am begginer with angularJS, I have no clue how to do that if there is no normal response. I got some a bit different response now. err: `{"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"https://testurl2019.com","headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer vgs7mJR7icPgMO2aOQAjzl71e8k5mwGx1OQncsefMl7OyPj8tgKfkvrSNpOi","Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"","xhrStatus":"error"}`

Comment: The status of `-1` and `xhrStatus` of `"error"` usually indicates that the browser blocked the request because of [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) security violation. The browser Developer Console should show an error message with more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. It was pretty dumb mistake from my side. On mac I was using adobe premiere pro 2018 and the chromes user-agent for it was much newer. And on windows I used 2015 version and the chromes user-agent is much older. So I updated to 2018 and voila, the old and new versions are working also on windows. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

In crome try ctr+shift+i, you will land to developer console where you can see the error details and line. This status generally occurs when the browser error comes or request blocks by browser.